# MATLAB: Implementing Least Squares Estimator for a Given Model

Tags: matlab, finite-impulse-response, moving-average, state-space, least-squares

The formula to estimate $\mathbf{h}$ is then
 $$\hat{\mathbf{h}} = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T \vec{y}\tag{2}$$

I think this can be implemented in Matlab using `hat_h = pinv(X)*X*y`

**Question 1 :** What is the lag of the model?

**Question 2:** I don't know how to create the design matrix `X` in order to estimate `h`. Can somebody please provide the complete implementation? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation you're trying to solve is
$$
\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{X}\mathbf{h},
$$
where $\mathbf{h}$ is your unknown. The matrix $\mathbf{X}$ is going to have a time-shifted structure that reflects the convolution operator. If we assume that the $\mathbf{y}$ vector starts with y(3) i.e. ignores the first two zeroed out elements of y,  then the corresponding $\mathbf{X}$ matrix is given by:

$$
\mathbf{X}=\left[\begin{matrix}
x(3) & x(2) & x(1)\\
x(4) & x(3) & x(2) \\
x(5) & x(4) & x(3) \\
... & ... & ...
\end{matrix}  \right]
$$

You can add as many rows as you are have observations to support them. You can then solve for $\mathbf{h}$ by 
$$
\mathbf{h}_{est}=\text{pinv}(\mathbf{X})\mathbf{y}
$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The structure of `X` starts from the third element and there are 3 coefficients. So, is this an MA model of order 3 or order 2? Can you please let me know?

Comment: Your system is represented by a quadratic polynomial - thus having 2 roots, so it's a 2nd order system.

Answer (score 2):

If X is your design matrix then the matlab implementation of Ordinary Least Squares is:

```
    h_hat = X'*X\(X'*y);
```

I attempted to answer your other question here: [How to apply Least Squares estimation for sparse coefficient estimation?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40655/how-to-apply-least-squares-estimation-for-sparse-coefficient-estimation) which explains how to create the design matrix.

As mentioned this is a second order Moving Average model, lag of 2. https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/48